# How to hide the close button on the Home/default tab (TabControl)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `TabControl` and a close button in each tab. I want to hide the close button from the first (default) tab. I used WPF MVVVM. [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfS4s.png) of my user interface.

This is the XAML code for the `TabControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Money_Transfer_System.Views.TabControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Money_Transfer_System.Views"
              xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Money_Transfer_System.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
   <UserControl.DataContext>
      <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
   </UserControl.DataContext>
   <Grid>
      <TabControl Name="mytabcontrol" SelectionChanged="mytabcontrol_SelectionChanged"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" Margin="10,0" SelectedItem="{Binding TabSelected}" >
         <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="st">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Padding="10" />
                  <Button
                            Name="closeButton" 
                            Content="X" Cursor="Hand" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Focusable="False"
                            FontFamily="Courier" FontSize="9" FontWeight="Bold"  Margin="0,1,0,0" 
                            Width="16" Height="16" Padding="0" 
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveTab,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
               </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
         </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
         <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <!--this is the body of the TabItem template-->
            <DataTemplate>
               <ContentControl Content="{Binding  Content}"></ContentControl>
               <!--<TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Content}" />-->
            </DataTemplate>
         </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
      </TabControl>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is my `WindowViewModel` code:

```
using System;
using DevExpress.Mvvm;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using DevExpress.Data;

namespace Money_Transfer_System.ViewModels
{
   public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
   {
      public ObservableCollection<Object> Tabs { get; set; }
      public MainViewModel()
      {
         var item = new TabItem { Content = "this is the main Tab", Header = "Home Tab" };
         Tabs.Add(item);

      }
      public class TabItem
      {
         public string Header { get; set; }
         public string Content { get; set; }

         public int path { get; set; }
      }

      private ICommand _addTab;
      private ICommand _removeTab;
      public ICommand AddTab
      {

         get
         {
            return _addTab ?? (_addTab = new RelayCommand(
                x =>
                {
                   AddTabItem();
                }));
         }
      }

      private void AddTabItem()
      {
         var header = "Tab " + tabs;
         String content = "Content " + tabs;
         var item = new TabItem { Content = content, Header = header };

         Tabs.Add(item);
         tabs++;
         //OnPropertyChanged("Titles");
      }

      public ICommand RemoveTab
      {
         get
         {
            if (_removeTab == null)
               _removeTab = new RelayCommand(param => this.RemoveTabItem(param), null);

            return _removeTab;
         }
      }

      private void RemoveTabItem(object param)
      {
         TabItem tabItem = (TabItem)param;
         //var z = param;
         //MessageBox.Show(param.ToString());
         this.Tabs.Remove(tabItem);
      }

      public bool ButtonVisibility
      {
         get { return false; }
      }
   }
}
```

I used a visibilty converter, but it did not work and I hope someone helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `bool` property `CanClose` to the `TabItem` class.

```
public class TabItem
{
   public bool CanClose { get; set; }
   // ...other properties.
}
```

Then add an instance of a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` to the `Resources` of your `TabControl`.

```
<TabControl Name="mytabcontrol"
            SelectionChanged="mytabcontrol_SelectionChanged"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
            Margin="10,0"
            SelectedItem="{Binding TabSelected}">
   <TabControl.Resources>
      <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
   </TabControl.Resources>
   <!-- ...other code. -->
</TabControl>
```

Bind the `Visibility` of your button to the property using the converter.

```
<Button   Name="closeButton" 
          Visibility="{Binding CanClose, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
          .../>
```

Finally, set the `CanClose` property to `true` for added tabs. The home tab will get `false` by default in the constructor of the `MainViewModel`.

```
private void AddTabItem()
{
   var header = "Tab " + tabs;
   var content = "Content " + tabs;
   var item = new TabItem { Content = content, Header = header, CanClose = true };

   Tabs.Add(item);
   tabs++;
}
```

As a note, consider implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `TabItem` model, otherwise changes to the properties will not be reflected in the UI.

Comment: Thank you very much .It is work  ,I'm grateful to you.

Comment: Can you please  ,explain how to implement (INotifyPropertyChanged) in TabItem to reflected the change in UI.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the SelectionChanged eventhandler, to hide the Button in code:

```
        if (tabControl.SelectedIndex == 0)
            closeButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        else
            closeButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this way dose not work because i can't reach to the name   of close button from the code behind, the Post below solve the problem